# Creating a PostgreSQL DML Change History Table

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

Although I have created a function and trigger to store the history of DML operations in the dml_history table, it is not working as expected. Could you please let me know if there's any specific error message or behavior that indicates what might be wrong?

Feel free to provide more details or the specific issue you are facing so that I can assist you more effectively.

```
-- employee Table
CREATE TABLE employee (
    employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_name VARCHAR(100),
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

-- department Table
CREATE TABLE department (
    department_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    department_name VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Create dml_history table
CREATE TABLE dml_history (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    record_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    action_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    changed_columns TEXT,
    action_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

-- Function for the trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_dml_changes()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    sql_query TEXT;
    changed_columns_text TEXT := '';
    col_info RECORD;
    col_name TEXT;
    record_id_value TEXT;
BEGIN
    sql_query := TG_TABLE_NAME;

    EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || quote_ident(column_name) || ' FROM $1'
    INTO record_id_value
    USING NEW;

    FOR col_info IN (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME) LOOP
        col_name := col_info.column_name;

        -- NEW and OLD Column check
        EXECUTE 'SELECT CASE WHEN $1.' || quote_ident(col_name) || ' IS DISTINCT FROM $2.' || quote_ident(col_name) || ' THEN
            $3 || ' || quote_literal('''' || col_name || '''') || ' || '': '' || $1.' || quote_ident(col_name) || ' || '', '' ELSE '''' END'
        INTO changed_columns_text
        USING NEW, OLD, changed_columns_text;
    END LOOP;

    -- not change column is skip
    IF changed_columns_text = '' THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    -- last , delete
    changed_columns_text := substring(changed_columns_text from 1 for length(changed_columns_text) - 2);

    -- Insert Info to history Table
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO dml_history (table_name, record_id, action_type, changed_columns, action_timestamp) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)'
    USING TG_TABLE_NAME, record_id_value, TG_OP[1], changed_columns_text, NOW();

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


-- Create triggers for tables (Example: employee table)
CREATE TRIGGER employee_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION log_dml_changes();

-- Create triggers for tables (Example: department table)
CREATE TRIGGER department_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON department
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION log_dml_changes();

-- Insert some sample data
INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, salary) VALUES ('John Doe', 50000.00);
INSERT INTO department (department_name) VALUES ('IT');

-- Update data
UPDATE employee SET salary = 55000.00 WHERE employee_name = 'John Doe';

-- Delete data
DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee_name = 'John Doe';

-- View the change history
SELECT * FROM dml_history;
```

When I tested with a single table, there were no issues.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_name VARCHAR(100),
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE employee_history (
    action_type CHAR(1), -- 'I' for INSERT, 'U' for UPDATE, 'D' for DELETE
    employee_id INT,
    employee_name VARCHAR(100),
    action_timestamp TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_employee_changes()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO employee_history VALUES ('I', NEW.employee_id, NEW.employee_name, NOW());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO employee_history VALUES ('U', NEW.employee_id, NEW.employee_name, NOW());
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO employee_history VALUES ('D', OLD.employee_id, OLD.employee_name, NOW());
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER employee_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION log_employee_changes();


-- Sample Data Insert
INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, salary) VALUES ('John Doe', 50000.00);
INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, salary) VALUES ('Jane Smith', 60000.00);

select * from employee_history;

-- Sample Data Update
UPDATE employee SET salary = 55000.00 WHERE employee_name = 'John Doe';

-- Sample Date Delete
DELETE FROM employee WHERE employee_name = 'Jane Smith';

select * from employee_history;
```

Comment: Can you format the code it will be easier to understand the problem...

Comment: Should you get in  log_employee_changes the exact result like the second example in the single table test? if so there is simple way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Should you get in log_employee_changes the exact result like the second example in the single table test? if so there is simple way to do that..

I did it in a special schema - dml

create the schema and the tables:

```
CREATE SCHEMA dml;

-- employee Table
CREATE TABLE dml.employee (
    employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_name VARCHAR(100),
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2)
 );

-- department Table
CREATE TABLE dml.department (
    department_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    department_name VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Create dml_history table
CREATE TABLE dml.dml_history (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    action_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    changed_columns hstore,
    row_data hstore,
    action_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT null,
    record_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

create the function log_dml_changes its will get two parameters:

1. the tableName
2. the pk column for record_id (if all the table have the same serial column like "id" you can change the code and send just the table name..

   ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dml.log_dml_changes() RETURNS
     TRIGGER AS $body$
    DECLARE
        dml_history_row dml.dml_history;
        h_old hstore;
        h_new hstore;
        table_name text;
    table_pk text;
    BEGIN
    IF TG_ARGV[0]::text IS NOT NULL THEN
       table_name = TG_ARGV[0]::text;
    END IF;
   IF TG_ARGV[1]::text IS NOT NULL THEN
       table_pk = TG_ARGV[1]::text;
    END IF;
     dml_history_row := ROW(
        nextval('dml.dml_history_id_seq'), -- id SERIAL
        table_name,                                   -- table_name
        substring(TG_OP, 1, 1),                       -- action_type
        NULL::hstore ,                                -- changed_columns
        NULL::hstore ,                                -- row_data
        statement_timestamp(),                         -- action_timestamp 
        null::integer
    );
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
      dml_history_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*);
      dml_history_row.changed_columns =  (hstore(NEW.*) - dml_history_row.row_data);
        IF dml_history_row.changed_columns = hstore('') THEN
            -- All changed fields are ignored. Skip this update.
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
        dml_history_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*);
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
        dml_history_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*);
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    IF table_pk is not null and dml_history_row.row_data -> table_pk is not null THEN
        dml_history_row.record_id = (dml_history_row.row_data -> table_pk) ::integer;
    end if;
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO dml.dml_history SELECT $1.*')
    USING dml_history_row;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
    $body$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
    SET search_path = pg_catalog, public;
   ```

Create triggers for tables (Example: employee table):

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON dml.employee
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION dml.log_dml_changes('employee','employee_id');
```

Create triggers for tables (Example: department table):

```
CREATE TRIGGER department_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON dml.department
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION dml.log_dml_changes('department','department_id');
```